# Does the div or any html element visibility affect the "mouseenter" function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If my div is set to `visibility:hidden` will that affect the behavior `onmouseenter` or `onmouseout` functions?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it will. Despite that the element remains visually in the document flow by leaving a space, you can't mouse-in to it because it is not visually on the page.

Comment: Did this not respond to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Something which is hidden is absent in the page.
so you can't invoke any mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although it still catches some space in the flow, you can't interact with it.

[See example here](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/pdhLx).

Answer (score 0):

yes it will get affected. As the div is hidden, mousein, mouseout and other related events will not be triggered. Check this [silly](http://jsfiddle.net/kantu/5Xrjd/) fiddle.

```
$("#foo").mouseout(function(){ // This will stop being triggered once its invisible
```